# How to Modularize Long Code

Tags: java, android

I have over 900 lines in my MainActivity because I can't figure out how to make other classes work.

It works but it makes it hard to read and tedious to update.

I will give an example of what I would want to separate to another class.

I would like to call this from the main activity.

MainActivity:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.apm:
            apm();
            return true;
    }
```

}

```
public void apm() {

            AlertDialog levelDialog;
            final CharSequence[] items = {" Reboot ", " Reboot Recovery ", " Hot Reboot "};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("What do you want to do?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            rooted();
                            reboot();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            rooted();
                            recovery();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            rooted();
                            softreboot();
                            break;
                        //case 3:
                        //shutdown();
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            });
            levelDialog = builder.create();
            levelDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: I need to know how to use the attached code in a separate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new class called Util (for example) in a new file, Util.java.

In this class put:

```
public static void apm(MainActivity activity){
    //Put the code from your old apm method here.
    //Whenever you need to call a method that is part of MainActivity
    //just prepend activity. in front of the method call.
}
```

Then in MainActivity, call `Util.apm(this);`.

EDIT:
Here's more detail. Put the following in Util.java and call `Util.apm(this);` in your MainActivity.

```
public static void apm(MainActivity activity) {
        AlertDialog levelDialog;
        final CharSequence[] items = {" Reboot ", " Reboot Recovery ", " Hot Reboot "};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("What do you want to do?");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        activity.rooted();
                        activity.reboot();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        activity.rooted();
                        activity.recovery();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        activity.rooted();
                        activity.softreboot();
                        break;
                    //case 3:
                    //activity.shutdown();
                    //break;
                }
            }
        });
        levelDialog = builder.create();
        levelDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: When you say MyActivity, do you mean my MainActivity?

Comment: I did that but calling Util.apm(this); must be used with a static method.. So I wont be able to do what I am trying to do since my apm method can't be static.

Comment: Yes, your MainActivity. I'm not sure what you mean by saying it can't be static. If you pass in your activity, and prepend all your method calls with `activity.`, then it's just as good as a non-static method.

Comment: You mean prepend it with Util. in this case? Thats what I did but it requires apm to be a static method in Utils. That would be fine, however, when it gets to "AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);" it says, "this" can't be used in a static method.

Comment: Replace it with `AlertDialog.Builder(activity);`. In your old method, the word "this" was referring to the instance of your activity, so you need to replace it with the instance you pass into Util.apm(activity).

Comment: I updated my explanation with an example of the method in Util.

Comment: Thank you so much. You just opened a big door for me. If I could upvote I would.

Answer (score 1):

you can write your apm method in another class. From your mainActivity, you can instanciate that class and pass the context of the activity to the constructor of the class.

then from mainActivity, just call the methods of that class using the class instance.

I hope you understand what I try to say. In your new class, you can access mainActivity components using the context you received in constructor.